# What is the minimum of the function $[0,1]\to[0,\infty), \lambda \mapsto e^{-aλ^2}+e^{-b(1-λ)^2}$, where $a>b>1$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, elementary-functions

Doing some estimates in machine learning, I stumbled into minimizing the following function:
 $$f :[0,1]\to[0,\infty), \lambda \mapsto e^{-aλ^2}+e^{-b(1-λ)^2},$$ where $a>b>1$. However, imposing the derivative equal to zero, finding in this way the minimizing point and then substituting the point into the function, seems not to work well since it is not clear how to find an explicit formula for $\lambda$ such that $f'(\lambda)=0$. Any other ideas how to find an elementary expression for the minimum value of this function?

Comment: Why do you think that there is an analytical solution to $f'(\lambda)=0$?In the limit $a>b>>1$, you can safely use $\lambda=0.5$. For smaller values, the function will have a minimum at $\lambda=1$

Comment: The fact is that $a>>b>1$ in the case I'm dealing with, so I sense that I can do better than $\lambda=1/2$. Actually, I have no reason to think that there is an analytical solution, but since I'm trying to get the best estimate for computational reasons, I'm here asking if anyone has some idea about it...

Comment: In that case your function is two peaks, one centered on $0$, one centered on $1$. With very large both $a$ and $b$, if you are not very close to the ends of the interval, the value of the contributions from each peak goes below the numerical precision of the machine. Say if $a=1000$, at $x=1/2$ you get $e^{-ax^2}\approx 2.7\cdot 10^{-109}$. If you are using 32 bit floating point numbers, the smallest positive number you can write is on the order of $10^{-44}$